# rados list-inconsistent-obj gives "Operation not permitted" error

Tags: ceph

When "rados list-inconsistent-pg " returns several inconsistent pgs such as ["1.12","1.2c","1.2d","1.57"], "rados list-inconsistent-obj " gives "Unknown error (1) Operation not permitted".

What should I do to correct his error?

-- update:
"ceph health detail" returns:

```
HEALTH_ERR 8 scrub errors; Possible data damage: 4 pgs inconsistent
OSD_SCRUB_ERRORS 8 scrub errors
PG_DAMAGED Possible data damage: 4 pgs inconsistent
    pg 1.12 is active+clean+inconsistent, acting [2,1]
    pg 1.2c is active+clean+scrubbing+deep+inconsistent+repair, acting [2,1]
    pg 1.2d is active+clean+inconsistent, acting [2,0]
    pg 1.57 is active+clean+inconsistent, acting [1,2]
```

Comment: lets try to solve it. First thing first, what does your `sudo ceph health detail` says?

Comment: @BKN-بیکےاین: I append update info to the post

Comment: Another thing to add is that if you really have a pool size of 2 you'll probably be facing difficulties repairing those PGs. If there are only two copies, how can ceph determine which one is the correct one? I advise to increase to pool size = 3 in order to avoid that or at least have better chances when trying to repair PGs. Do other ceph/rados commands work as the same user? Or do you run all commands with the admin client & keyring?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your  `sudo ceph health detail`, first thing is to get help of following general repair command:

`ceph pg repair {pgid}`

In your case it would be:

- `ceph pg repair 1.12`
- `ceph pg repair 1.2c`
- `ceph pg repair 1.2d`
- `ceph pg repair 1.57`

Also, please try to **backup** the PG copies you are repairing.

**Limitations of Ceph repair**:
My experience says that [Ceph repair does not automatically repair placement groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66704113/ceph-pg-repair-doesnt-start-right-away) when inconsistencies are found in them. For instance [this](https://docs.ceph.com/en/latest/rados/operations/pg-repair/) also explains why repair will *not* automatically solve it. There are chances you have to manually diagnose like [this](https://ceph.io/geen-categorie/ceph-manually-repair-object/).

**Dig deeper**:
In addition to it, I maintain following helpful notes for solving PG inconsistencies in my cluster:

- [PG inconsistent with empty inconsistent objects](https://lists.ceph.io/hyperkitty/list/ceph-users@ceph.io/thread/CAGQIIIY3E4D5E7QMIKITKZXUT6IQCKT/)
- [How to recover from active+clean+inconsistent+failed_repair?](https://lists.ceph.io/hyperkitty/list/ceph-users@ceph.io/thread/TI6RM5GUAX5PGERCQVZZ6JMZXQQ3O7OZ/)
- [Scrub Error / How does ceph pg repair work?](https://ceph-users.ceph.narkive.com/2OSM6EuW/scrub-error-how-does-ceph-pg-repair-work)
- [PG show inconsistent active+clean+inconsistent](https://ceph-users.ceph.narkive.com/32fChmCF/pg-show-inconsistent-active-clean-inconsistent)